# How many zero divisors in $(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z)[X]/\langle X^n \rangle$ with $n\in\Bbb N_+$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R=(\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$)[X]/ $\langle X^n \rangle $ with $n\in\Bbb N_+$. Show that $f\in R$ is a zero divisor if and only if $f_0=0$. And how many zero dividers exist?

I know that zero divispr means there exists non-zero $m$ such that $fm=0$ in $R$  and that $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ has no zero divisors, meaning $f_0$ or $m_0$ are equal to $0$ if $fm=0$.

How can i show that if $m_0\neq0$ then $f_0=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element of $R$ has a unique representative of degree less than $n$; this shows that $|R|=5^n$.

By construction you have $X^n=0$ in $R$. This shows that $X$ is a zero divisor, because $X\cdot X^{n-1}=0$, where $X^{n-1}\neq0$. But by the exact same argument every (non-zero) multiple of $X$ is a zero divisor; for every $g\in R$ you have 
$$(X\cdot g)\cdot X^{n-1}=X^n\cdot g=0\cdot g=0.$$
Of course an element $f\in R$ is of the form $X\cdot g$ if and only if $f_0=0$, so this shows that if $f_0=0$ then $f$ is a zero divisor.

Conversely, if $f\in R$ is a zero divisor then there exists some non-zero $m\in R$ such that $fm=0$, meaning that $fm$ is a multiple of $X^n$. Because $m$ is non-zero it is not a multiple of $X^n$. So for the product $fm$ to be a multiple of $X^n$ it must be the case that $f$ is a multiple of $X$, meaning $f_0=0$.

This shows that an element $f\in R$ is a zero divisor if and only if $f_0=0$. Because every $f\in R$ has a unique representative of degree less than $n$, this means the number of zero divisors of $R$ is $5^{n-1}$.

Do consider carefully what happens with this argument when $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you ! How would i continue to find the units in R ? I think that the units in R are only 1,2,3,4

Comment: Those are indeed units, but they are not all. A nice exercise in commutative algebra is to show that in a finite ring, every element is either a unit or a zero divisor.

Comment: I think that would be way too advanced for my current level :D. Any easier way i could find them ? So according to you there are 4*$5^{n-1}$ units ?

Comment: Can i argument that every f which isnt a zero divisor is a unit ? thus $5^n-5^{n-1} = 4*5^{n-1}$

Comment: Without context it is not an easy exercise. But let me give you a hint; for each element $r\in R$, consider the map given by multiplication by $r$, i.e. 
$$R\ \longrightarrow\ R:\ x\ \longmapsto\ xr.$$
What does it mean for this map to be surjective? And what does it mean for the map to be *not* injective?

Comment: An alternative approach would use the fact that all zero divisors of $R$ are in fact *nilpotent*; for every zero divisor $f\in R$ you have $f^n=0$ (why?). It follows that
$$(1-f)(1+f+f^2+\cdots+f^{n-1})=1-f^n=1,$$
which shows that $1-f$ is a unit. Can you make this argument work for any unit $u\in R$? (in stead of just for the unit $1\in R$)

Comment: if its surjective then r is a unit i guess if its not injective then r is a zero divisor

Comment: That's right; can you prove it?

Comment: I dont see how this helps me though :D ?

Comment: Because $R$ is finite, a map $R\ \longrightarrow\ R$ is surjective if and only if it is injective. So every such multiplication map is either surjective, or not injective.

Comment: OHHHH I SEE . Thats a very nice trick :D Thanks i got it

Comment: You're welcome :) Consider accepting this answer, so this question doesn't stay in the 'Unanswered' queue. And answers to your other questions as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Any element in $R$ is the class mod. $X^n$ of exactly one polynomial of degree $<n$ in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$. Such a polynomial corresponds to a zero-divisor if and only if it is  divisible by $X$, i.e. it is of the form $\;XP(X)$, with $\deg P<n-1$. These polynomials are determined by the sequence $(c_0,c_1,\dots , c_{n-2})$ of their coefficients. In other words, they're in bijection with $(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^{n-1}$.